# Mapbox runtime styling - unable to add MGLFillStyleLayer with source

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm following the demo from this https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/commit/61df0b1bfa0cd43bcc9a87f73f7ece6fbb9b4175 , adding a source with identifier "test" then the layer with identifier "test-layer".

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("amsterdam", ofType: "geojson")
let geoJSONURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath!)
let source = MGLGeoJSONSource(sourceIdentifier: "test", geoJSONData: NSData(contentsOfURL: geoJSONURL)!)
mapView.style().addSource(source)

let fillLayer = MGLFillStyleLayer(layerIdentifier: "test-layer", sourceIdentifier: "test")
fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.greenColor()
mapView.style().addLayer(fillLayer)
```

but the layer is not drawn on the map, when I tried to print the information of the layout I find the sourceIdentifier of the layer is `nil` and when I tried to fetch the source using the identifier `test` it throw error.
[image]

How can I add and display the layer correctly?

Comment: I have the same problem like you. Currently developing with Swift for iOS 10 and Mapbox iOS SDK v3.4.0-alpha.4. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @rmnblm It seems that's because I forgot to specify `reuseIdentifier` when creating a MGLAnnotationView, after I added that it works.

Comment: @rmnblm https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/6485